# c# SshClient RunCommand error

Tags: c#, bash, runcommand

Through SshClient I can connect to the machine, but when I run the code:

```
using (var client = new SshClient(_server, _user, _password))
                {
                    client.Connect();

                    var commandResult = client.RunCommand("obj <- Service$new()");
```

var commandResult2 = client.RunCommand("obj$setJsonData(" + json + ")");

```
                    var response = commandResult.Result;
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
```

I get this error:
Payload cannot be more then 32768 bytes

How to set a larger size?

Comment: what are you connecting to? thats not a very bash looking command.. what do you expect that command to do

Comment: Sorry my problem has changed. When I run:

Client.RunCommand ("obj $ setJsonData (" + json + ")");

Which should start processing, I get this error: Payload cannot be more then 32768 bytes

Comment: How to set a larger size?